# Google spreadsheet API, 400 error bad request : unable to parse range

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api-client

I am trying to access Google spreadsheets using a spreadsheet example. When I run the example code it worked fine. I just change the **SpreadsheetId** and range. It started giving me:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Unable to parse range: Class Data!A2:A4",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Unable to parse range: Class Data!A2:A4",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at poc.mainPOC.main(mainPOC.java:157)
```

Below is the code:

```
  String spreadsheetId = "my spread sheet ID";
    String range = "Class Data!A2:A4";
    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
        .get(spreadsheetId, range)
        .execute();
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Try replacing `Class Data!A2:A4` with `A2:A4`

Comment: i want to access a particular spreadsheet how can i do it ?     ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
              .get(spreadsheetId, range)
             .execute();    Currently i'm using this to get data

Comment: In the example it seems like 'Class Data' was the name of the worksheet. If there are no sheets with that name, then it throws the error. @HemantYadav when you say spreadsheet, do you mean worksheet? If it's spreadsheet then you provide the spreadsheetId. If it's worksheet, you provide it in the range like "NameOfWorksheet!A2:A4" where NameOfWorksheet is the name of the worksheet including spaces. By omitting the NameOfWorksheet and exclamation mark, it goes to the first worksheet.

Comment: Can you please answer for my question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096279/inserting-datas-into-google-sheets-api-using-javascript  @ritesh.garg

Comment: Thanks a ton bro. And the explanation by @zeta is puts a lot  unknown things into perspective.

Answer (score 25):

If you look at the sheet [itself](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit) you will notice that the Worksheet is titled "Class Data". So just put the name of your sheet where is says "Class Data". Example: 
String range = "SheetName!A1:C";

Answer (score 16):

`String range = "Class Data!A2:A4";`

The `Class Data` is your worksheet's name, FYI: the name on the tab at the bottom, the default one is "Sheet1". Replace `Class Data` with the one you want to work with.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to add some data to a sheet named `Emmett` that did not existed yet and was receiving this error:

`Error: Unable to parse range: Emmet!A2:C12`

I had to manually create the sheet named `Emmett` in the spreadsheet and then it worked like a charm.

Comment: I had the problem because I was opening the wrong document (dumb bug confusing the input and output spreadsheet IDs).  It is unfortunate that the error message is not 'can't find sheet "Emmet"' instead of complaining about parsing the range expression, because the syntax is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this error when I had a typo in the name of the tab. In your case "Class Data" didn't match the name of the tab

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was an extra space in the google sheet while I was trimming the sheet name at my end. Once I removed the trimming logic, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I learned was that If the column name doesn't exist yet, this command won't be able to find it. You need to make sure the column you're writing to already exists -- I did this manually from the google sheet.