# Data validation with One of range rule in Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to implement data validation where the rule is one of the range using Google Sheets API.

In sheet1, I have a master list where one column needs to be in one of the values. The possible dropdown values are in a separate sheet called dropdown.

What is the error in my conditional value for one_of_range?

```
dropdown_action = {
'setDataValidation':{
    'range':{

        'startRowIndex':1,
        'startColumnIndex':4, 
        'endColumnIndex':5
    },
    'rule':{
        'condition':{
            'type':'ONE_OF_RANGE', 
            'values': [
                { "userEnteredValue" : "dropdown!A1:B2"
                }
            ],
        },
        'inputMessage' : 'Choose one from dropdown',
        'strict':True,
        'showCustomUi': True
    }

}
}

request = [dropdown_action]
batchUpdateRequest = {'requests': request}
SHEETS.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId = id, 
                             body = batchUpdateRequest).execute()
```

However, I encountered into http error. I was able to get it working if I choose one of list instead of one_of_range. But I prefer to use one_of_range so that I can maintain the possible values in the same spreadsheet.

HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/id:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid requests[1].setDataValidation: Invalid ConditionValue.userEnteredValue: dropdown!A1:B2">

Comment: [Error](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request) means that a required field or parameter has not been provided. Make sure that the value supplied is valid, or the combination of provided fields is valid. This can be also because the [request was malformed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning). In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893515/google-spreadsheet-api-400-error-bad-request-unable-to-parse-range).

Comment: Yes, I think the error comes from the combination of the rule condition type and values. I changed the code to 'type':'ONE_OF_LIST', 
                'values': [
                    { "userEnteredValue" : "A1:B2"
                    }
                ]. And it works. But I'd still like to figure out what the correct combination for one_of_range as the type.

Comment: Does it work if you put an '=' before the sheet name, e.g, `"=dropdown!A1:B2"`?

Comment: Yes, that works now thank you! You should add an aswer. Also it might be worth adding that to the documentation here https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#ConditionType

Answer (score 6):

As Sam Berlin suggested, the solution is to add '=' in the range.

"=dropdown!A1:B2" will work with one_in_range data validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing could work for me, and then I saw this subject 
[Google Spreadsheet API setDataValidation with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977942/google-spreadsheet-api-setdatavalidation-with-regex) , where ZektorH mark that "Your expression needs to be escaped".

Comment: *Please always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.* See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

This option helped me:

```
"userEnteredValue": "='dropdown'!$A$1:$B$2",
```