# Google Spreadsheet API setDataValidation with Regex

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Im trying to generate an Google Spreadsheet Template with some Validation with their API, using the Node.Js Package from Google.

**This is my current Request:**

```
{
 "setDataValidation": {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": 1656514345,
      "startRowIndex": 0,
      "endRowIndex": 0,
      "startColumnIndex": 1,
      "endColumnIndex": 1000
    },
    "rule": {
      "condition": {
        "type": "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
        "values": [
          {
            "userEnteredValue": "=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A2:A1000); '([1-9]){4}[-]([1-9]){2}[-]([1-9]){2}$')"
          }
        ]
      },
      "inputMessage": "TEST VALIDATION",
      "strict": true
    }
  }
```

}

**I get the following Error:**

```
Error: Invalid requests[0].setDataValidation: Invalid ConditionValue.userEnteredValue: =REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A2:A1000); '([1-9]){4}[-]([1-9]){2}[-]([1-9]){2}$')
```

A simple create or append Data in the Spreadsheet works fine, but getting an Regex Validation to work seems like the limit. In the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ConditionValue)  there seems no limitation for RegEx, what is wrong with my Request?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression needs to be escaped.

```
"userEnteredValue": "=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A1), \"[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}$\")"
```

Note that the internal quotes are escaped (`\"` instead of `"`).

Note that single quotes also won't work.

Comment: Yeah, That worked, Thank You! Is it possible to add Cell Validation on a Create Call, or only on an Update call? If not, is there a way to get the spreadsheetId and sheetId of the creat call?

Comment: @sHamann Please search on the documentation for information or submit a new question.