# Inserting Data's Into Google Sheets API Using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

Am trying to Insert My data's Into google Sheet API . So i followed this [Link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/writing#write_a_single_range)

After trying that am Getting no Error as `PUT 400()` in my console,
in my **Network Header**

```
    Request URL:https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1sd4HEFMsK3WJyHgcs1crX-30LqkBum30kxdH0qCwL5Y/values/Sheet1!A1:B1?valueInputOption==USER_ENTERED
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:400 
Remote Address:74.125.68.95:443
```

and my Network Response is

```
   {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'value_input_option' (TYPE_ENUM), \"=USER_ENTERED\"",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "value_input_option",
            "description": "Invalid value at 'value_input_option' (TYPE_ENUM), \"=USER_ENTERED\""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

. What i did wrong here , Or still i have to add stuffs into my code ? . Can someone Help/Clarify me  . Here is my HTML ,

```
<div ng-controller="BasicExampleCtrl">

<header data-ng-include="'app/views/header.html'"></header>
<div class="header" data-ng-include="'app/views/menu.html'"></div>
<h2>Welcome Google SpreadSheet Page</h2>

   <button class="btn btn-primary"
   data-ng-click="read()" style="position: absolute;width: 199px;height: 35px;left: 0px;top: 190px;">View In GoogleSheets</button>
</div>

<iframe id='ifr' src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sd4HEFMsK3WJyHgcs1crX-30LqkBum30kxdH0qCwL5Y/edit#gid=0'
style="position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;left: 0px;top: 250px;" >
 </iframe>

 <iframe id='ifr' src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sd4HEFMsK3WJyHgcs1crX-30LqkBum30kxdH0qCwL5Y/edit#gid=0'style="position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;left: 0px;top: 250px;" >
 </iframe>
```

Here is My Js Code ,

```
$scope.read = function () {

    var params = {
               "range":"Sheet1!A1:B1",
               "majorDimension": "ROWS",
               "values": [
               ["Hello","World"]
              ],
         }  

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('PUT', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1sd4HEFMsK3WJyHgcs1crX-30LqkBum30kxdH0qCwL5Y/values/Sheet1!A1:B1?valueInputOption==USER_ENTERED;headers=false');

     xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));


            };

    }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `valueInputOption==USER_ENTERED` instead of `valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`.  Two equal signs instead of one.  The error message is telling you the same: `"Invalid value at 'value_input_option' (TYPE_ENUM), \"=USER_ENTERED\""` -- `=USER_ENTERED` isn't a valid value, but `USER_ENTERED` is.

Comment: I found that on Yesterday , It was my Mistake..Anyway thanks @Sam Berlin :)

Comment: Am using `OAUTH 2.0 playground` `access_token` for Authentication Purpose but it valid's for just 1Hour only. How can i get Permanent Validation ?

Comment: Please ask a different SO question for that, @SaravanaKumar.