# Google Sheets_V4 API from Ruby: how to get_spreadsheet_values of named ranges

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet that contains a named range. How do I read the value of the referenced range from the api?
I have tried the

```
service.get_spreadsheet_values(doc_id, range)
```

example.
But if range is specified as 'myspecialrange' then I get

> badRequest: Unable to parse range: 'REHTEST'

I've been using the `getNamedRanges` from the javascript APP scripting environment and now needs this from the Rest API.

Comment: I am not sure what your code look like, it seems that you specified the value of `range` in `service.get_spreadsheet_values(doc_id, range)` as `REHTEST`. Take note that doc_id must be the `spreadsheet ID` and the `range` is the cells, rows or columns where you will be getting a value, example, `Sheet1!A1:A2`. In this scenario you will be getting the value from the cells `A1` to `A2` located in the `Sheet1` under to the spreadsheet ID you have specified. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893515/google-spreadsheet-api-400-error-bad-request-unable-to-parse-range/37893568).

Comment: I am aware of the use of the A1 notation. My problem is that the API states that you can use "named ranges" ... I don't know how to specify the named range and use this to get the value.